# What mobile network has the best 4G coverage in Indonesia?

Tags: cellphones, indonesia, mobile-operators, phone-networks

I want to use 4G as much as possible when traveling in Indonesia.

Does anyone know (has experience?) which mobile network provides the best 4G coverage in Indonesia?

Comment: I have a BOLT mini Wi-Fi 4G router, it's really fine compared to other internet options in Indonesia.

Comment: Feel free to elaborate in an answer :) You have actual experience of the coverage quality so it'd be awesome if you can share this further!

Comment: Only in some parts of Jakarta, didn't try it in other cities, so I can not really answer. Someone will come and say in x city it's bad..

Comment: Fair enough. Did you do a speedtest by any chance? How fast are you able to download/upload heavy files? Thanks

Comment: I am sure I did but I forgot, now it is deactivated as I got cable (I bought a house there), the times I am on the move I use a 3G sim card from Three and it is ok. I use the one from Three because it will be deactivated after one year of inactivity, unlike other providers which is one month period only.

Comment: Oh ok. You can share your experience with three here ;) http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53459/9395

Answer (score 5):

Some online articles have done the research for you:

[Who offers the best 4G LTE connection in Indonesia? Here’s our side-by-side comparison](https://www.techinasia.com/telkomsel-indosat-xl-axiata-bolt-4g-lte-indonesia/):

> For coverage, **Bolt takes the lead** by covering 750,000 users in Jakarta,
>   Bogor, Depok, Tangerang, and Bekasi areas. Telkomsel, the country’s
>   biggest operator, covers a few areas in Jakarta and Bali. While XL
>   Axiata mostly provides 4G speed in Bogor, Medan, and Yogyakarta. XL is
>   still holding 4G trials in Jakarta, mostly covering only Kelapa Gading
>   area in North Jakarta. Indosat’s coverage is quite small: a few areas
>   surrounding Jakarta’s Monas, Thamrin, and Sudirman districts.

Comment: I give a more develop answer below, but your quote explain well the absurdity of the subject. 750,000 user is 0.3% of the population and certainy less than 0.01% of the country area

Comment: I just came across [OpenSignal.com](http://opensignal.com/), it provides info on mobile network coverage (2G, 3G & 4G) on many countries for all the networks available.

Answer (score 1):

"I want 4G while traveling in Indonesia" !!!!???!!!

Unless you want to travel only in the center of big Javanese city, your request is as absurd as asking for only the best cheese on the Moon.

Indonesia is a Huge country and Indonesia is a POOR country. Not poor like Detroit city, mind you. Poor like "my son died because there was no running water at the hospital"

So, if you want 4G, OK... read Mayo's link. If you want to travel, accept that Edge is often the best you will get. And you won't always get it.

And the widest coverage is clearly Telkomcel. Unfortunately, it is also the slowest and more expensive).

As an illustration, I live in North Sumatra and everybody agree that Bold is the best 4G operator. But it work ONLY in Medan. It provides no network AT ALL in any other place (probably soon in Banda Aceh)

Comment: One may need it in specific occasions, i.e. To work remotely, download and upload big files, and so on. And 4G might be a simpler solution than running after "the hotel in town with a decent connection". If there is no 4G option, then one might go "good connection hunting". This is one use case....

Comment: I just read your answer again: why so much passion? Lol. Seriously. I travelled in Sumatra and realize most of it is third world. What I'm interested in is to find the best 4G provider at the moment, the fact that it only covers Megan at the moment is good info. No need to get so upset about the whole thing :)

Comment: Wow, poor with capital. I know Indonesia is not the best when it comes to internet connection (and other things), but it doesn't give you the right to call it a poor country.

Comment: @springgrolls Well... the fact that 2 children of aquitance children died from lack of basic medical care allow me to call it poor. Java and Bali may look "not worth than Thailand" but I live in Aceh countryside and I can tell you this country at large is MASSIVELY underdeveloped.

Comment: @Madlozoz Yes, I know these facts well enough. I am an Indonesian. But still I think your answer is rather rude, esp. that part with the capital poor. You are free to state the facts, but please do it with respect. Furthermore, this question is about internet service and not medical care or whatsoever. I think stating that Indonesia is lacking in internet infrastructure would be enough. Just my two cents.

Comment: @springrolls I understand your point, Indonesians may get offended. But Madlozoz also has a point, most of the population is poor (but seem happy nonetheless), so calling it otherwise is just silly. And it does explain why the infrastructures are still developing, to be fair, the 3G infrastructures are pretty good considering the state of the country. Hopefully this will help the population somehow.

Comment: @AdrienBe I'm not asking people to call Indonesia otherwise, but to communicate their opinions well. I am fully aware that some regions are poor, as you've probably already seen. But to state outright, Indonesia is a poor country without explaining more, may give other people a false impression. Anyway, I hope you had a great time in Indonesia :)